# which option can be used in :g command?

Tags: vim

I want to see the documentation of the :g command, so I type help :g, vim show the following picture
[image]
then, I want to see which command can be used(except p(print) and d(delete)), but I don't know how to do it, I try :help :cmd, but vim show the help for execute a shell command, not what I want.

Comment: You can use any `ex` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ex commands are listed in `:command` output (user/plugin-defined ones) and `:h ex-cmd-index` (built-ins).